# Double is rounding my last NSNumber decimal

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsnumber

For example

```
                    print(message.timestamp!)
```

gives me: 1470938337.572778

```
                    print(Double(message.timestamp!))
```

gives me: 1470938337.57278

I need to use the double to convert to NSDate like this:

```
date: NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: Double(message.timestamp!))
```

but I also need the timestamps to be accurate why is it rounding?

Comment: It seems to be working just fine http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/57acc49a603420ce5f482bb3

Comment: Is `timestamp` a string?

Comment: No, it's an NSNumber, It's really confusing why it's doing that

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov I tried it with 6 decimal places and it rounded to 5

Comment: @slimboy What input did you try, what output did you get, and what did you expect?

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov using the values you offered yourself on: 
[link] (swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/57acc49a603420ce5f482bb3)

I get

Input: let input: NSNumber = 1470938337.572778
Output:  1470938337.57278

The last 6th decimal is rounded.

I need to use the timestamp as an ID so it must remain 6 when converting to double

Comment: @slimboy Take a careful look at [this.](http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/57acc9bf603420ce5f482bb7). The literal value being assigned to `input` is `1470938337.572778`. What's printed (even whilst still in `NSNumber` form) is `1,470,938,337.57278`.

Comment: This is a case of exceeding the precision representable by an IEEE754 Double width floating point data type. The issue isn't in the `NSNumber` -> `Double` conversion (which makes sense, because `NSNumber` is a wrapper for a `Double`).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120735/discussion-between-alexander-momchliov-and-slimboy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this sample code:

```
import Foundation

let input: NSNumber = 1470938337.572778

print("   NSNumber: \(input)")
print("     Double: \(Double(input))")
print("doubleValue: \(input.doubleValue)")
```

**Output:**

```
   NSNumber: 1,470,938,337.57278 //not even this is printing correctly.
     Double: 1470938337.57278
doubleValue: 1470938337.57278
```

This is a case of exceeding the precision representable by an [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) Double width floating point data type. The issue isn't in the `NSNumber` -> `Double` conversion (which makes sense, because `NSNumber` is a wrapper for a Double).